# EntityFramework not expanding Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I create a FixtureScoringSession With Site and Client fillied with the clients site set the that of of the FixtureScoringSession. The data is intserted fine. When it comes to retrieving a FixtureScoringSession it only populates the Site and not the client. I have a feeling it has something to do with Client and FixtureScoringSession sharing the same Site. But it will include the Client if I specify Include.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Also if I keep the same instance of DbContext it works but if I get a new one it does not.

Entities:

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class FixtureScoringSession
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SpawtzFixtureId { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a mistake in your design if both Client and FixtureScoringSession share the same Site?

Comment: The issue is that a client can exist with a site so it needs a client and we also decided that FixtureScoringSession should have a site. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make the navigation properties `virtual` if you want them to automatically work that way.

Comment: That would make sense but why does site on FixtureScoringSession work fine?

Comment: What does the line of code look like that you use to load the FixedScoringSession?

Comment: We would need to see the two queries to be sure.